How many years can a Boeing 747 be in service?
Over the years, many 747s have been retired from passenger service, but some are still flying in other roles, like cargo transport. So, how long can a Boeing 747 remain in active service before it is retired or replaced?

Keep in mind that in addition to the excellent answer regarding strict regulatory requirements for inspection and/or reinforcement, a new plane of comparable capacity will have a much lower cost to fly due to using two newer engines instead of four older engines.

The 747 is has a design life of 35000 flight cycles (takeoff and landings) as it came from the factory (this could vary with model). Around 150,000 hours give or take.
Once you get to that level, you will be faced with a couple of options; reinforcing the structure to maintain the existing inspection intervals, or carrying on with much more frequent inspection intervals.
A lot of the structural inspections will require Non Destructive Test equipment like Eddy Current (which can find hidden cracks), and the expenses involved go through the roof if the intervals have to be reduced to much lower values to maintain fatigue safety margins.
The alternative may be to install reinforcements (sold by Boeing or a 3rd party as service bulletin or STC kits) to beef up the structure and restore it back to or close to the original inspection intervals.
One option involves recurring financial pain supporting frequent structural inspections, the other involves one big bout of financial pain to buy, say another 20,000 cycles of operation under the old inspection program by purchasing a reinforcement kit.
At some point, the business case no longer works for either option and it's just not profitable to operate it, and the airplane is put out to pasture, usually stripped clean of parts for resale or re-use, and the airframe sold for scrap.

It will depend on the length of the routes but 35000 cycles/ 150000 hours comes to something like 40 to 50 years for a typical use case?

A 747 average leg will be somewhere between 5-8 hours. Max endurance is well over 10. Flight cycle sensitive areas are landing gear structure, fuselage swelling with pressurization, that sort of thing.  If one does two legs/day. Maybe 500-1000 cycles per year. You could say 30-40 years is typical before the airframe is becoming too expensive to keep up. That's if corrosion doesn't do it in first. The inside of a pressurized fuselage gets very damp because the insulation gets very wet from condensate forming on inside of the outer skin. This ends up near the bottom and can rot the structure.

and even before corrosion or flight cycles make the aircraft uneconomical (or worse, unsafe) to operate there will be a time when operating cost due to consumables (fuel, oil, etc. etc.) starts to outstrip that of newer aircraft to the point that scrapping the 747 in favour of say a 777 freighter starts making sense (of course that also depends heavily on the operator, someone like say IranAir won't have easy access to replacement aircraft).

Yes.  Fuel price fluctuations are a huge factor.  Operators were retiring CRJ200s before their airframe lives were used up, because they were becoming too expensive to operate, but when fuel prices imploded following 2008, it gave them a new lease on life. Skywest was snapping up all the used 200s they could get their hands on.

In 2011, FAA and EASA adopted coordinated rules against widespread fatigue damage. At some point, large portions of the structure have reached their fatigue lifetime. Multiple cracks may form and start to merge and the whole airplane will blow apart, like Aloha Flight 243.
Thus, pressurized transport aircraft have had hard limits on flight cycles and hours since 2011. Any aircraft exceeding those limits loses its airworthiness certificate. Aircraft under the Soviet/CIS system have had such limits for many decades, this was finally adopted this in the West.
For the 747, there is a default limit of 20,000 flight cycles. Boeing has extended this limit to 35,000 flight cycles and 165,000 flight hours (-400, 135k FH prior models) with inspection and modification work.
This is a hard limit, so aircraft reaching that limit cannot be operated in FAA, EASA, and countries following their rules. Manufacturers will also end support at that time. The aircraft must either be scrapped, or it may find itself in countries with far lower aviation safety standards.

Interesting. That seems to contradict the other answer to a degree ("hard limit" is different than "install a reinforcement kit"). In any case I'd be curious to know whether this just affects commercial operation. After all, enthusiasts fly vintage airplanes essentially "forever". At some point it may be a "ship of Theseus", sure, but with enough love and care, shouldn't it be possible to keep even a large vessel airworthy (for non-commercial operation)?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: Due to the square cube law, replacing a strut on a vintage aircraft with an unreasonably strong one is snot likely to put the plane overweight.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica The LOV requirements on recent planes are written in Part 25 and the type certificate, so at expiration of LOV, the aircraft cannot be maintained to the TC. The avenue there would likely be to come up with an inspection regime and operate the aircraft under an experimental TC, which prohibits commercial use. Vintage aircraft have done this when major repairs are needed. For older planes certified before this rule, it's Part 121 that bans it, so non-air carrier operation may be possible, though it's also been deemed unsafe, so again, going to an experimental TC is likely.
